# Как сетевой концентратор выбирает адресата?

Tags: сеть, администрирование, маршрутизация, протоколы, пакет

Если, например, объединить 5 компьютеров в сеть с помощью концентратора. И отправить данные с компьютера "1" на компьютер "3". Как концентратор поймет кому именно отправлять, он же по идее только копирует сигналы во все порты и все остальные компьютеры тоже получат эти данные в любом случае (даже если они им не предназначались)?

Comment: Концентратор отправляет все всем.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, концентратор (он же "хаб") тупо копирует трафик на все порты и более ни о чем не думает. И все компьютеры в сети видят весь трафик и сами выбирают интересующие их пакеты.

В отличие от него, коммутатор (от же "свитч"), анализирует трафик и запоминает в таблице коммутации, с какого порта шли пакеты от каких исходящих MAC-адресов. При получении любого пакета, если этот пакет послан не на широковещательный MAC, он ищет MAC назначения в таблице коммутации и если находит - то отправляет пакет только в тот порт, где этот MAC есть. Если же не находит - то отправляет на все порты, так как же как и широковещательный трафик.

Comment: Т.е. если я, к примеру, захочу отправить личное сообщение либо файл через концентратор конкретному компьютеру, чтобы другие не видели, так сделать не получится, они по-любому увидят?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев да, именно так. остается вопрос где вы в наше время нашли концентраторы. их не выпускают уже лет 8 и они преимущественно были на 10 MBit. 100 MBit в принципе попадались, но были очень редким зверем